# FabricJS I-text clone issue

Tags: html, fabricjs

When we have a i-text as selected and we clone it. On the cloned object, double click, start editing, after that try to unselect and it will not.

On kitchensink example

http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/

Go to execute tab and add this code

```
var selectedObject=canvas.getActiveObject();
var object = fabric.util.object.clone(selectedObject);
            object.set("top", object.top+5);
            object.set("left", object.left+5);
            canvas.add(object);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is the solution!

```
var oldobj = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    newobj = oldobj.clone();

newobj.set("top", newobj.top+20);
newobj.set("left", newobj.left+20);

canvas.add(newobj);
canvas.setActiveObject(newobj);
canvas.renderAll();
```